# How do I create a webpart that displays a single document?

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation

I'm revising the question to clarify what I need with more concrete examples. The solutions offered so far have led me to refine my questions.

I am creating an online reference system on a page that's got a left nav bar populated with an index list. When a user clicks on one of the index items, the document to which its linked should open up on the right side of the page and remain until ANOTHER document is selected. The index is static, the content is dynamic....

```
       Browser Window
 +-----------+------------+
 | document1 |  documentN |
 | document2 |            |
 | document3 |   based on |
 | document4 |  left nav  |
 | document5 |  selection |
 | document6 |   <<<<<    |
 | document7 |            |
 | document8 |            |
 +-----------+------------+
```

I need a web part that displays a web page, not a LIST of web pages. Each time I try to display a page currently, it opens full-screen in IE, not in the right hand panel. If I were coding this with frames, I'd use `<a href="document1.html" target="right-hand-frame">` on every document. Hoever, I don't know if this can be done in SP or how to make it work.

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In speaking with a colleague from another company last night, he directed me to the page viewer web-part, (Insert > Web Part > Media & Content > Page Viewer) which is a predefined single-page view template. Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint Foundation I'd create a Team site for the reference.

Create all the "documents" as wiki pages in "Site Pages"

Change the master page to display a list of all the pages instead of the default left menu.

Comment: The documents are already as wiki pages, @PerJakobsen. While I can get the page listing, there's not a way I've found to open the selected document within the Sharepoint environment--it opens in its native application at fullscreen. Is this a setting somwhere?

Comment: If they are wiki pages then there is no native app.

Answer (score 1):

You could rely on an Enterprise Wiki site template to store your pages.

You could then easily use the Navigation settings (under Site Settings-Navigation) to control (manually or automatically) the Left-navigation (under Current Navigation Settings) to  via the option to "Show Pages" (uncheck "Show Subsites") and specify even how to group pages (via the heading - single Level supported only).

This should do it with only OOTB features, just focus on your content, no actual need to create a different page (or web part).

Comment: Just for clarification, @CMarius, we're using Foundation. Is the enterprise wiki available for that platform? or is this MOSS or above?

Comment: Enterprise Wiki (or Publishing sites for that matter) come with Standard Edition (or above), so i would say that it does not apply in this case,  not in this way! What i mean is that even with collaboration sites you have Wiki Libraries and Quick Launch control, therefore you should envision at least do it this way!